# python - lock process accessing queue queue while queue.put() for n seconds

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code (simplified):

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f1(queue):
    while True:
        # do some stuff and get a variable called data
        # ...

        queue.put(data)

def f2(queue):
    while True:
        if not queue.empty():
            data = queue.get(timeout=300)
            print('queue data: ' + str(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=f1, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=f2, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to lock the queue in `f1` in order to keep putting data for **n** seconds, before `f2` is able to read it.

I tried with timeouts but of course, it didn't work. Basically, the expected behaviour would be that `f1` keeps appending data into the queue and after **n** seconds, `f2` can get what's in that queue. So, summarising, `f1` should be running continuously, `f2` should be running continuously too but accessing the queue every **n** seconds.

I can think of *not so elegant* ways of doing this with the time library, but I guess it has to be other way. Maybe the code's approach is wrong and I shouldn't be using Process and Queue but Pipelines or something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Finally used a `sleep(n)` even though there are more elegant solutions, for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular case in which I was using the multiprocessing library, instead of *threading* or *asyncio*, I found the best way to do this by using a simple sleep, so the `f2()` will end up like:

```py
def f2(queue):
    while True:
        time.sleep(300) # sleep for 5 minutes before POSTing
        if not queue.empty():
            data = queue.get(timeout=300)
            print('queue data: ' + str(data))
```

Of course, after importing `time`.

As I said, maybe not the most elegant solution but I couldn't come up with anything better for the time being (and this particular use case).